# Use Raspberry and Arduino IDE to programm ESP8266

Tags: arduino-ide, esp8266, uploading, raspberrypi

I currently use Arduino IDE to generate binaries for ESP8266. Afterwards I copy the binaries with SFTP to my Raspberry Pi and flash the binaries using esptool.py.

These are lots of steps I need to do manually. Is it possible to automate this and use the Raspberry Pi as a programmer known to the Arduino IDE?

The goal is, that the "Upload" button in Arduino IDE does the full job.

Comment: Are you running the Arduino IDE on Windows, Linux or macOS ?

Comment: IDE is running on Windows.

Comment: You could try using serial over IP ( http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/SerialNet ). Alternatively add the OTA updating to the ESP so you can do away with the Pi entirely.

Comment: You could switch over to an entirely command-line workflow, and then a Makefile would suffice. You will bash/cygwin/some other *nix environment on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The OTA option looks interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution based on this post: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/serial-over-lan-from-linux-to-windows-825334/#post4062960

Following steps are necessary.

- Install `com0com` and `com2tcp` on the Windows machine and `socat` on the Raspberry.
- Then add a virtual COM-pair (`COM0 <-> COM25`) on the Windows machine with the help of `com0com`.
- Execute following command on the Raspberry. `socat file:/dev/ttyAMA0,raw,echo=0,b115200 tcp-l:3016,fork&` (adjust the device `/dev/ttyAMA0`, baudrate `b115200` and port `3016` according your needs)
- Start `com2tcp` on the Windows PC with following command. `com2tcp --baud 115200 --ignore-dsr \\.\COM25 192.168.0.1 3016`
- Now you can use `COM0` in Arduino IDE to flash the ESP8266 attached to `/dev/ttyAMA0` on the Raspberry

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing Python for Windows?

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/win/

In theory it should work and you should be able to run esptool.py on a Windows command line like you do on your Pi (provided that your usb to serial in recongnized by Windows).

If esptool.py fails to run under Python for Windows I would first suggest to open a ticket with the esptool maintainer and then try under a cygwin environement (https://www.cygwin.com).

Comment: I think, I forgot to mention, that I don't have a USB UART Interface on my PC. So there is no way to program over UART and without the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Get a FTDI adapter. Here is a blog post I wrote a while ago about it : http://net-forces.blogspot.ca/2016/07/flashing-esp-01-under-osx.html?m=1